# could not select subreport - .rdlc - VS 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, reporting-services, rdlc, subreport

I had created many reports with VS 2008.  Now starting with VS 2010 for new requirement.  Please note I am using .rdlc report

- I could add subreport control to the report but could not select the available reports.  There is no browse button or a dropdown to choose the available .rdlc report.
- When I manually type the report name, the reportviewer doesnt show up any subreport.  I dont see any error message on the 'Output' window either.

How do I use subreport with VS 2010?  Am I missing anything?  Any help is appreciated.

I have SQL 2005/2008 (report services installed), VS 2008, VS 2010 installed on the same PC.

Comment: Are all the reports in the same solution? Did you try building the solution file again?

Answer (score 0):

First select sub report from Toolbox and put where you want to show.See the image bellow
[image]
Now right click on sub report properties and type your sub report name .
[image]

Now You have to create a sub report  even handler in your .cs file from where you load your report like that:

```
public Ctor()
{
    string path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("Your Report path");
    ReportViewer1.Reset(); //important
    ReportViewer1.ProcessingMode = Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ProcessingMode.Local;
    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SubreportProcessing += Process_Subreport;
    LocalReport objReport = ReportViewer1.LocalReport;
    objReport.ReportPath = path;

    // Add Parameter If you need 
    List<ReportParameter> parameters = new List<ReportParameter>();
    parameters.Add(new ReportParameter("Name", Value));
    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(parameters);
    ReportViewer1.ShowParameterPrompts = false;
    ReportViewer1.ShowPromptAreaButton = false;
    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();

    //Add Datasourdce
    ReportDataSource reportDataSource = new ReportDataSource();
    reportDataSource.Name = "Datasource Name Used due to report design";
    reportDataSource.Value = DataSourceValue;
    objReport.DataSources.Add(reportDataSource);
    objReport.Refresh();
}
```

Now Create Even Handler Method to load sub report  details.

```
private void Process_Subreport(object sender, SubreportProcessingEventArgs e)
{
  //You can get parameter from main report 
  int paramname = int.Parse(e.Parameters[0].Values[0].ToString());
  //You can also add parameter in sub report if you  need like main report

  //Now add sub report data source     
   e.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("DataSource Name",DataSourceValue)));
 }
```

I think it will be works for you.Thank you.

Comment: heloo, i need help, i follow the above code but there is error when pass parameters. "sub report could not be shown"