# how to print data from a DB in c# via Winform Application?

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, printing

I am looking for a simple way to print data from a `Sql DB` using my `Winform Application`
but I want to able to customize it.  Like adding titles and being able to decide where each thing will be on the printed page.  I found a lot of questions like mine, but didn't get/understand the answers.  I am looking for the most simple way that it can be done.

Thanks for all the help.

Comment: subirshan you need to show what you have tried or at least make an effort to show what code you have. this is not a `code complete` forum meaning... we are not here to write the code for you. there are `1000's` of examples out there on the web about printing as well as retrieving data from Data base and printing..

Comment: Have you tried Reporting Services? [This article](http://geekswithblogs.net/Patware/archive/2009/03/13/130070.aspx) gives an introduction

Comment: i am sorry . 
i tried to read about the print controllers that are provided in the toolbox but with no luck .

Comment: i wanted to know the general idea of how this can be done . if i need to implement a class of some sort or using a dll or something . i have no background about this spacific thing. sorry again for the trouble

Comment: Look into [ADO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e80y5yhx.aspx).NET.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in Visual Studio 2010 you have access to both Crystal Reports and the Microsoft Reporting tools, I'd recommend that you start there.

There are plenty of tutorials on the web for Crystal reports. Here is one on codeguru:
http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_graphics/chartsandgraphing/article.php/c10483/Beginners-Guide-to-Crystal-Reports-Part-I-Winforms.htm

and here is one for the Microsoft Reporting tools, right here on stackoverflow:
[A Tutorial For Microsoft Report In WinForm Applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6124093/a-tutorial-for-microsoft-report-in-winform-applications)

It appears the VS2012 doesn't come with Crystal reports, but it may be available. There are other report libraries available on VS2012 NuGet