# Printing reports from DataTable in C# .net

Tags: c#, .net, printing, reporting

I need to print some data form my DataTable. I always use PrintDocument class for printing but now i have some database data that would be easier to print using reporting. I used to work in VB6 and used it's datareporting and it is very easy but I can't figure out how to use it in c#.

Also I'm creating application for .net 2.0.

Comment: u can use this way : http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2012/01/crystal-reports-sample-in-aspnet.html

Comment: I can install crystal report using VS, but I don't know how to use it on computer that doesn't have VS installed on it?

Comment: U need to install Visual studio and crystal report also..

Comment: Is there any way to do it without installing visual studio?

Comment: No visual studio is must for making any report.

Answer (score 0):

You can use RDLC with ReportViewer control.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252067.aspx

Here is a nice tutorial for using RDLC.

[A Tutorial For Microsoft Report In WinForm Applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6124093/a-tutorial-for-microsoft-report-in-winform-applications)

Comment: It's good but it only shows how to print all data from table? How to find data using certain criterion.

Comment: You can create DataView from DataTable and apply RowFilter. see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview.rowfilter.aspx